# compile C code for iOS (arm) 32-bit using clang

Tags: ios, c, clang, jailbreak

I wanted to compile a Hello World C using macOS Terminal.  The target was iOS (ARM) 32-bit devices.  My default compiler choice was `Clang`.

Directly with Clang..

`clang -arch armv7 main_3.c -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -o helloWorld`

But remember, if you put this onto a jailbroken device, you need to sign the code!

`security find-identity -v -p codesigning`

`codesign -s <developer_identity> helloworld`

then get your file to the device. I use Cyberduck with SFTP.

Comment: Simplest way is probably to run an iOS compile of a .c file in Xcode and examine the build log to see the command line.

Comment: if `-target arm` isn't doing it for you perhaps the clang build you're using wasn't built with the arm backend. It works [here](https://godbolt.org/g/6mmUb9).

Comment: wow @bames53. That site is exactly what I was after.